# Deploy Django on Apache 2.4

Tags: django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I have been trying to deploy my Django application on ubuntu 14.04 with the installed packages which are:

```
django 1.4.15
apache 2.4
python 2.7
mod_wsgi 3.4 (there is one compiled as mod_wsig.so-2.7 which is the one I use)
```

on my apache config I have this fields:

```
# Modules
LoadModule mpm_worker_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7
LoadModule setenvif_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule authn_core_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so
...
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
# And finally the app config.
WSGIPythonHome /home/web/.virtualenvs/web
WSGIPythonPath /PATH/TO/MYSITE:/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / "/PATH/TO/wsgi.py"
```

Everything seems to be fine until I try to import one of the local modules in my system. By this I mean, the wsgi.py script runs no problem and then the django settings.py start running, in the settings I have this code:

```
from MYSITE.environments.prod_settings import *
```

environments is a module with it's own `__init__.py` file and all. but when it reaches that line it can't import.

The other part is that the site runs perfectly when I run `./manage.py runserver` and the info in the sys.path is just the same!

I am just out of ideas on why apache wsgi will not let me import that python module.

Here is the latest logs:

```
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:06.222374 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3639:tid 140258688976768] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.322057 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472] /home/web/.virtualenvs/web   <--- printed the sys.prefix
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673877 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472] 2014-11-28 18:07:09,670 (3642/MainThread) newrelic ERROR - Falling back to stderr logging as unable to create log file '/var/log/newrelic/newrelic-python-agent.log'.
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673930 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673941 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]   File "/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.28.0.26/newrelic/common/log_file.py", line 79, in initialize_logging
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673950 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]     _initialize_file_logging(log_file, log_level)
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673959 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]   File "/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.28.0.26/newrelic/common/log_file.py", line 51, in _initialize_file_logging
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673969 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]     handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673977 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 903, in __init__
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673985 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.673993 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 928, in _open
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.674001 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.674009 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/newrelic/newrelic-python-agent.log'
[Fri Nov 28 18:07:09.985905 2014] [:error] [pid 3642:tid 140258619721472] No module named wizzytest2   <---- My module name
```

After the module error the logs errors are about problems with database connections in general. This happens because in the wizzytest2 module I have settings overrides so that is expected.

```
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.923879 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008] '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web'  <-- python home
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924177 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008] ['/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924230 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/MYSITE/mysite',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924256 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/src/python-itunes',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924287 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924312 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924342 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924366 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924395 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924419 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924449 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924483 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924557 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924583 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.28.0.26',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924615 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924641 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.28.0.26',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924663 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/MYSITE',
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:44.924695 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008]  '/home/web/MYSITE/mysite']
[Sat Nov 29 21:37:45.474168 2014] [:error] [pid 6097:tid 140297485195008] No module named wizzytest2
```

Just added the python path too so it's easier to debug. I also fixed the newrelic issue but that doesn't makes any difference on the settings file `wizzytest2` been found or not.

Comment: Did you try to launch you ``runserver`` with ``django-admin.py``, in other directory than your project ?

Comment: And can you give the ``ImportError`` messages and apache error logs ?

Comment: just updated the answer with the logs.

Comment: Where is located ``wizzytest2`` and is it a package (directory) or module ?

Comment: is a directory with it's own __init__.py. I managed to make django work without trying to import this wizzytest2 which is at least something. Still, I do need this type of behaviour for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Now with your logs I think the trouble is evident:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/newrelic/newrelic-python-agent.log/'
```

The user which launches your application doesn't have the right to write in `'/var/log/newrelic/newrelic-python-agent.log'`.

Maybe `chmod -R +w '/var/log/newrelic/'` can help you. But in fact, you should place the user which launch your app in an appropriate group which can write logs.

> Note:
>   You should use [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) for control you app and only use apache as frontend.

Comment: I know about the newrelic issue. The thing is, that shouldn't affect python reading or not the settings file `wizzytest2` to override some fields. My main question is why it can't find that file which is on the python path?

Answer (score 0):

At the end this was an issue with permissions on the overriding settings file I wanted to import, at the end I just needed to do a `chown web:web` to the file and a `chmod`.